# Your opinions on the SQLitePlus COM dll please

Tags: sqlite, com

This is a dll sold by a company called ez tools software.

Am wondering if you've used this component and what your experience was like in your dealing with them.

The company website is somewhat unconventional but perhaps this is to be expected considering the underlying product is open source.

Would really appreciate your opinion on this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the free [dhRichClient](http://www.thecommon.net/2.html) in production -- it's been performing great.

Looks like SqlitePlus is wrapping quite the same ADO-style functionality.